# Fixing a return value for a switch statement using a for loop

Tags: java

I recently tried messing around with a blackjack game, however everytime my deck pulls an ace it automatically assigns the ace the value of 11 and not the value of 1 based on the total value of the cards in my hand.

```
public class Deck {

private ArrayList<Card> cards;

public Deck(){
    this.cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
}
public int valueOfCards(){
    int totalValue = 0;
    int aces = 0;

    for(Card aCard : this.cards){
        switch(aCard.getValue()){
        case TWO: totalValue += 2; break;
        case THREE: totalValue += 3; break;
        case FOUR: totalValue += 4; break;
        case FIVE: totalValue += 5; break;
        case SIX: totalValue += 6; break;
        case SEVEN: totalValue += 7; break;
        case EIGHT: totalValue += 8; break;
        case NINE: totalValue += 9; break;
        case TEN: totalValue += 10; break;
        case JACK: totalValue += 10; break;
        case QUEEN: totalValue += 10; break;
        case KING: totalValue += 10; break;
        case ACE: totalValue += 11 ; break;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < aces; i++){
        if(totalValue > 10){
            totalValue += 1;
        }
        else{
        totalValue += 11;
        }
    }
return totalValue;
}
}
```

Comment: And ???????????

Comment: I was trying to get the value of an ace to be 1 if the users hand is already 11 or above

Comment: please post a [mcve] and remove useless part (like the for loop at the end) Possible hint: `aces = 0` always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `aces` is never modified, so the loop after the `switch` does nothing.

In the `switch`,
if the card is an `ACE`,
you don't want to add 11.
You want to increment the number of aces in `aces`,
and let the next loop do its job.

That is, this single line change should fix your program:

```
case ACE: aces++ ; break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well your code looks like it's supposed to count the aces in the first loop which it doesn't. You probably want to do something like

```
case ACE: totalValue += 11; aces++; break;
```

to increment the ace count for the later loop.
However I'd guess it would be easier to first sort the cards by their value to make sure the aces are at the end, and then you can just do

```
case ACES: totalValue += (totalValue > 10) ? 1 : 11;
```

and leave out the second loop altogether.

Incidentally, you might as well give your "Value" enum a member and method

```
public enum CardValue {
    TWO(2), THREE(3), // and so on

    private int value;
    private CardValue(int value) { this.value = value; }

    public int getValue(int currentHandValue) {
        if (this == ACE) {
            return currentHandValue > 10 ? 1 : 11;
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

so your current code reduces to

```
// make sure aces are at the end
List<Card> sorted = new ArrayList<>(cards);
Collections.sort(sorted, Comparator.comparing(Card::getValue));
int totalValue = 0;
for (Card c : sorted) {
    totalValue += c.getValue(totalValue);
}
return totalValue;
```